# How did GE get this background to fix and scale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I'm trying to get a background image to behave like GE's background on their website:
http://www.ge.com/stories/powering-gas-engines.html

I was wondering what CSS or javascript techniques they were using to get that kind of effect.

Comment: can you be more specific? There several effects you may be refereeing to.

Comment: The way the background picture of the man stays centered as the window width is extended and how the picture stays fixed when the length is extended.

Comment: It looks as if the file ge.js may be where the css is being manipulated on window resize.  Somewhere around line 64 is where I start seeing instances of 'resize' and 'window' together, but I am definitely NOT a javascript person so I don't know if that is what it is referring to there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin that can help you accomplish this, and he's laid out the code in his description to give a good idea of how it all works.  What I like about this one is it also maintains aspect ratio.

http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking between that one and this one:http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Comment: That looks like a good one as well, a little more features.  Thanks, I'll be adding that one to my bookmark collection.

Answer (score 0):

it is an image, rather than a background image, and they use a javascript function called from the onresize event to set the width and/or height of it to the full width of its containing div.

It is possible to create a similar effect by using the css3 background-size property, but this is only supported in the css3 compliant browsers.

Answer (score -1):

css `width: 100%` for both container and background image and use media queries to control minimum windows size to use elastic width or fix width